# Disable onClicklistner while other touch listner is active

Tags: android, android-layout, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I am trying to implement UI like google keep.
In the main layout there is frame layout in which there is a FAM(Floating Actions Menu) and a blackshadow view which is visible when FAM is expanded.

What i want is that when i touch the shadow view it should Collapse the FAM. To do that i have implemented onTouchlistner on shadowview.

```
shadowview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(fam.isExpanded()){
                fam.collapse();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But what happens is that when i touch the area with MyCardGridView's card (Which open's another activity) open's another activity. Which should not happen.

[image: MainActivity]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use `return true;` instead of `return false;`, because as the documentation says :

> Returns:
>   True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise.

Maybe the issue here is caused by `return false`